# setting python object property not changing value

Tags: python

If you look at my code below, I'm creating a FileNode and passing it the string(filename). When the filename setter is triggered it should then populate the remaining fields, however it doesn't appear to work.

I'm currently just trying to test setting the property 'extension' within the 'filename' setter, but it doesn't seem to change the property, Why is this?

```
import os
import pprint

class FileNode(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.show = ""
        self.episode = ""
        self.sequence = ""
        self.shot = ""
        self.task = ""
        self.version = ""
        self.extension = ""
        self.isValid = False

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.filename

    @property
    def extension(self):
        return self.extension

    @filename.setter
    def filename(self, value):
        self._filename = value

        fl, ex = os.path.splitext(value)
        self._extension = "candles"

    @extension.setter
    def extension(self, value):
        self._extension = value



a = FileNode("BTMAN_1005_001_007_model_cup_v001.max")
# print (vars(a))
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)
pp.pprint(vars(a))

b = FileNode("BTMAN_1005_001_007_model_v001.max")
# print (vars(b))
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)
pp.pprint(vars(b))
```

Comment: It *does* change `extension`, but you set it to `""` at the end of `__init__`.

Comment: @JokerMartini I'm not one of the voters, but I guess they're putting it on hold because it seems like a typo.  Where you initialise the class - you explicitly set `self.extension` to `""` ***after*** you try to set the extension in `@filename.setter`.  If you move `self.extension = ""` before `self.filename = filename` in `__init__()`, it will work as (I assume) you intend.  I guess you'll want to change `"candles"` back to `ex`, too.

Comment: @JRichardSnape thanks Richard. I'm rather new to python so it may seem simple to others where it's new to me. So thank you for explaining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your properties have the same names as the attributes!

Try using names beginning with a single underscore for the attributes, as in

```
...
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self._extension = ""
    ...
...
@property
def extension(self):
    return self._extension
...
```

Comment: This doesn't change it either, i still have the same problem.